# Can we call celery delay or apply_async within an async python function

Tags: python, celery, python-asyncio

Assuming Redis is our Celery message queue. is apply_async considered a blocking I/O function, in other words, is this correct code in django 3.1 view, or will it block the event loop and needing sync_to_async wrapping:

```
async def django_view(request):
       celery_task.apply_async()
       return success_page
```

Comment: apply_async() is not blocking as far as I know, but who knows how whether it calls some blocking functions or not...

Comment: Yea, it will at least interact with redis (directly or indirectly) to push a task onto the queue, and redis being a blocking I/O.

Comment: I dunno, Python asyncio has become a serious solution when it comes to high performance IO (talking to databases and other network IO), and it feels like the question of how to use Celery and Python asyncio is an important one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen that with FastAPI, if the redis db is down all the application hangs waiting for a connection.
With "all the application" I mean that other requests are stuck as well.
This means that the coroutine that makes the call is not suspended: it's waiting on a sync call and blocking all the others.

This is an example on how I solved:

```
self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop() 
partial_delay = lambda: entry.celery_task.delay(
    command_type=entry.command_type, command_body=entry.command_body
        )
self.loop.run_in_executor(None, partial_delay)
```

Comment: Yea, it blocks. The solution of course would be to to run it in a separate thread, for example by using await asyncio.get_running_loop().run_in_executor(None,block_func)